# Localhost WEB Api always return 400 Bad Request

Tags: asp.net-core, networking, xamarin.forms, localhost, webapi

I'm using a real Android device. When I try to call WEB Api I get 400 Bad Request. The API is located on localhost (IIS Express). But if you call Api from windows application then everything is fine.

Windown application API string - https://localhost:44399/api/v1/families - return 200 Ok

Android application API string - https://192.168.0.102:44399/api/v1/families - return 400 Bad Request

My ipconfig:
Wireless LAN adapter Wi-Fi:

Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :

Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::4dbf:c945:4125:74c8%5

IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.0.102

Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0

Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.0.1

I tried different ways: I connected to the local network, to my wifi network, nothing helped.

Comment: you need to look at your IIS logs.  Potentially enable request logging so you can compare in detail the request that works with the one that does not.

Comment: 400 - client side. IIS has not reached yet

Comment: Um, no.  "In these scenarios, IIS has rejected the client's HTTP request because the request did not meet the server's HTTP parsing rules, or it exceeded time limits, or failed some other rule that IIS or HTTP.sys require incoming requests to adhere to. IIS sends the HTTP 400 - Bad Request status back to the client, and then terminates the TCP connection."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The requests would be routed to “192.168.0.102” but it doesn't work for IIS Express by default.

Please follow the below steps.

Before that, replace your application API `https://localhost:44399/api/v1/families` address to `https://192.168.0.102:44399/api/v1/families`.

1. Download [Jexus Manager](https://www.jexusmanager.com/) and install.
2. Open the `Jexus Manager` by Administration privilege.
3. Click here and set up the IIS(Check with your VS version) - [Managing IIS Express Servers](https://docs.jexusmanager.com/getting-started/features.html#managing-iis-express-servers).
4. Go to Edit site -> bindings

[image: Jexux manager]

5. Add new binding with correct values and the Hostname should be your host machine local IP address. In your case `192.168.0.102`.

   - after the add new binding, it shows as, ( in here my local IP address is 192.168.1.101. after the binding your one it should be your host machine IP address.)
     [image]
6. Run the server.

Answer (score 0):

So far it sounds like this is correct behavior. You are getting a 400 bad request, meaning that you are reaching the server, but you are not sending over the request correctly.

This could be that you aren't sending over the body or parameters correctly, or are missing some.

Try to take a look at what your Android device is trying to send to the server, and you'll likely find your issue.

Answer (score 0):

[@MRSessions](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11191898/mrsessions) is absolutely right. we are reaching the application server. But there is problem in request format. Possibly the header of the request. Please try using different headers like Accept: application/json, content-type: application/json etc.

You can easily match what is being sent during you hit it in browser or postman and the android via Logcat. Here is how:

Try using [postman](https://www.postman.com) for api testing and note all the headers. Now you will know everything in details about the request.

Then use this [Http Logging Interceptor library](https://github.com/square/okhttp/tree/master/okhttp-logging-interceptor) for logging all the requests being sent. But you need to use the OkHttpClient or Retrofit in that case.

I've also faced these kind of bad request problems so many times. I get read of them after comparing the postman request format and android request format. The Http Logging Interceptor will display each and everything about request format in Logcat. You can also read them in access logs of your server.

In this android video course the it uses Laravel and the same way in android I'm suggesting. Please try, this might help you.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=StFvAYmg04o&list=PLEubh3Rmu4tn8xtkVcWnWOjQcGG4aeRK-